# Importing a class from another source file that's in another directory

Tags: java, import

```
.
├── addition
│   └── Add.java
└─ main.java
```

This is the current file structure of my program. And these are the contents of `main.java`. and `Add.java` respectively.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("First number: ");
        var user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = user_input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Second number: ");
        int y = user_input.nextInt();

        var result = addition.Add.add(x, y); // <-- error in this line
        var output = x + " + " + y + " = " + result;
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Add {
    public static int add(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

I am unsure how I'm supposed to import the `Add` class into `main.java`. Not sure if it matters but I go to the root of the project and run `javac *.*`. To compile all the java source files.

Comment: You should be using `packages`

Answer (score 0):

If can use IDE: eclipse,   and then import package addition

All code like this:

Add.java:

```
package addition;

public class Add {
    public static int add(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

main.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import addition.Add;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("First number: ");
        Scanner  user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = user_input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Second number: ");
        int y = user_input.nextInt();

        Add add = new Add();
        int result = add.add(x, y); // <-- error in this line
        String output = x + " + " + y + " = " + result;
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: the `add` method is static